# Implement Blockly widget into Flutter

Tags: flutter, blockly, google-blockly

I'm new into Flutter and I'm trying to add Blockly into Flutter for an app for kids.
I want to be able to program some code into a Flutter app with Blockly, practically I'm trying to create a route with inside a Blockly widget in which the kid, through Blockly, can codes some simple programs and these are used by the Flutter app to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to use Blockly as a widget inside your app. A way to do that is to create a route that has a WebView widget in order to display Blockly:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/blockly',
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I get the response send from Blockly?

Comment: Well, your app will have to communicate directly with Blockly via http calls. I have not worked with Blockly so much before, you should see if they have an exposed rest API that you can communicate with in order to get your data.

Comment: @RaduHrihoreanu so I want to use blockly in my windows desktop application.
can I use webview widget with the above URL to work on?

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ according with the WebView library documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter this widget is only for Android and iOS platforms is I don't think it will work on a desktop application. You can try this library instead: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows . Is a webview library created for web project. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @RaduHrihoreanu Yesterday night I already tried that package but I encounter this new error https://cutt.ly/1AHcgh1